# How to Stop bubbling of STYLES in a partial view which is render through AJAX call to main view, in MVC SPA

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

In my  MVC/SPA project I want to stop Bubbling of styles which are in a specific partial view.

It's hard to copy the hole code from project I will try to describe in short with an example.

I have Main view currentpage.cshtml in which I have 3 buttons(Button1, button2, button3), onclick of each button I make an Ajax call(3 separate AJAX calls for each button) to show different POPUP's(_partial1.cshtml, _partial2.cshtml, _partial3.cshtml).
here comes the issue. in one partial(_partial1.cshtml) view I have a some styles which should be applied for this POPUP only, but the CSS in that Partial is bubbling to Main View which is effecting the Styles of my other popups.

Suggestions Please??

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for, I think, is the scoped attribute on a style tag. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp. But as you can see, http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped, it isn't supported very well in all common browsers.

The best thing you can do for now is adding scope to your CSS by yourself with an unique wrapper (class, id, name).

Comment: Thank you Tom. Yes for Now i did that,  added scope using Class, but wondering does Asp.net provide any helpers for this case.

Comment: As far is I know ASP doesn't have any helpers for this case. So adding scope your self is the best thing you can do.